# asp.net bulleted list and css menus

Tags: css, menu, asp.net-2.0

Is there a decent CSS menu that will work with the asp:bulletedlist control?

I've looked at a few different implementation, but most of them (i.e - see http://www.exploding-boy.com/images/center/center.html) rely on a span tag to contain the link text.

Or is there a way to force the bulletedlist control to render the link tag using spans?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a bulleted list control, you might want to use a repeater control and just use the item template with your own version of the markup code:

```
 <li><span><a href="#"><% data text field %></a></span></li>
```

I have found this a little easier to work with than with the more complex controls offered by the framework.